# PHP/Mysql Query Output Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need a hand here with some PHP/MySql please.

This is what my database looks like: http://cl.ly/2v022Y1w352r1x091Y3C

And this is how I need to output it: http://cl.ly/0V2X120M3H1R1G3z0B2Y (in the case that product = 'canvas' and type = 'single_pane')

I'm struggling to find a way to output the database into that table. I'm guessing I would need to group the rows by the same product, type, width, and height. I'm really not sure how to do this, I looked into the "GROUP" MySql function, but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a crosstab query, and this is your man for MySQl.

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html

His example is complicated but it might help. And this one is a little less daring: http://www.leghumped.com/blog/2008/11/16/crosstab-queries/

Chuck